# Converting TSQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I need cities count for each state and all columns of states table in select result set.
I have TSQL query but dont know how to tackle inner query and grouping in LINQ.

States Table

```
StateID,StateName,Description,Address,SectionName
```

Cities Table:

```
CityID,StateID,Address,Description
```

Here is TSQL query need to be converted to LINQ

```
declare @State varchar(100)
set @State='IL'

SELECT s.*,oCities.CityCount
from ( 
        Select c.StateID,count(*) CityCount
        from States s inner join Cities c on 
        s.StateID =c.StateID 
        where s.StateName =@State
        group by c.StateID 
    ) oCities inner join States s on oCities.StateID = s.StateID 
where s.StateName =@State
```

Preferably in C# language but any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/172141)

Comment: Oded, Yes, I know its not for translation. I have written simple LINQ queries to perform simple selection but got stuck with this queries hence decided to look for help. I am experienced but new to LINQ yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your foreign keys have been defined and imported correctly then something like this should work

```
var state = states.Where (s => s.StateName == name).Select (
    s => new {State=s, CityCount=s.Cities.Count()}).SingleOrDefault ();
```

Using Linq to SQL this translates as

```
SELECT [t2].*, [t2].[value] AS [CityCount]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].*, (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [City] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[StateId] = [t0].[Id]
        ) AS [value]
    FROM [State] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE [t2].[StateName] = @p0
```

where p0 is your @state parameter.

Comment: the first solution worked but I had to join and re-import tables because they were not joined before and I did want it either. -thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var q1 = 
from c in cities
join s in states 
on c.StateID equals s.StateID
where s.StateName=statename
select new {city=c, state=s};

var result = q1.GroupBy(x=>x.state.StateID)
                .Select(x=>new {Count = x.Count(), state = x.First().state});
```

Comment: I got compile time error :"inner join s in states on s.StateID equals s.StateID" I removed inner then the error was gone but getting null reference exception at run time: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @Needo, I wrote `s` in both parts, one part should be `s` and one part should be `c`, use my edit.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed and corrected before running query but still getting null reference exception. I am newbie with LINQ so dont know whats wrong with it but the data looks correct because TSQL query returns correct data.

Comment: @Needo, Ok run it step by step, first do: var q3 = q1.ToList(), then tell me what is in q3 (or exception).

Comment: You don't use 'inner' in LINQ.  Missing brackets. Produces two SQL statements.

Comment: @Phil, as OP said he removed inner from his query, I'd forget edit it but now I fixed it, but I can't understand what do you mean by two SQL statement?

Comment: You query is translated as 'select count(*) from ... group by ...' and then 'select top(1) ... from city ...'.  You're still missing a closing '}'.

Comment: Also your query works in similar manner, if I have two select (not inner) in server side doesn't cause to any problem, both of them are O(n), and there is no performance issue, but If I fetch data two times this causes to problem, but as you can see I just fetch it one time (also my comment for calling ToList is just for debugging issues).

Comment: Another problem.  Your query is returning the count of states not cities, so always returns Count = 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10660/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-phil)